# How to know email is send from custom button

Tags: custom-button, leads

I have a custom button which redirects me to the salesforce standard email sending page. Also in activity history , there is one send an email. Now i need to change the lead status to in progress if we send email using the custom button. How can i come to know that the email sent is using that custom button ?
Here is my custom button code

```
    if ('{!Lead.OwnerId}' != '{!User.Id}'){
alert("{!$Label.SFA_SendEmail_NotAuthorized}");
}else{

location.replace('{!$Site.BaseUrl}/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?p2_lkid={!Lead.Id}&rtype=00Q&retURL={!Lead.Id}');

}
```

Comment: The button merely brings up a page allowing user to construct an email.  You want to know if user then actually sent email? What if user changes their mind and clicks Cancel? That seems like a normal thing to do.  If you need to force sending an email, have your custom button update a field that then triggers a workflow that sends the email unconditionally.

Comment: Yes exactly as you say !! I need to update the status field only if the mail sent from that custom button

Comment: does the email use a fixed subject line or a specific templateID that would never be used by any other email send action?

Comment: the subject will be entered by the user It may get changed for every email

Comment: without some specific field in the Task or Email that is associated to the specific button, I'm not sure how you can do this